# Tracking updates to a text column within an after update trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a DB designed in SQL-Server 2000 but running in SQL-Server 2008.
One of the tables has a `TEXT` column with notes in, I need to track the number of changes made to this column.

Currently there is a trigger inserting values from the inserted:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[NotesEdited] 
   ON  [dbo].[NOTESTABLE] 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @UserID VarChar(4);
DECLARE @DateEdited datetime;
DECLARE @NotesAfter varchar(max);
DECLARE @PRIMARY float;

SELECT @UserID = user_edited FROM inserted;
SELECT @PRIMARY = note_primary FROM inserted;
SELECT @DateEdited = GetDate();
SELECT @NotesAfter = (select note from NOTESTABLE where note_primary = @PRIMARY)

IF UPDATE(note)

    BEGIN

        insert into NotesEditHistory (DateEdited,NotesAfter,UserID) values(@DateEdited,@NotesAfter,@UserID)


    END 


END
```

The big problem is the software performs between 2 and 10 updates of the table, only one of which has a change to the `note` field but results in 2-10 inserts into the table.

I thought this would be worked around using the line `IF UPDATE(note)` but it seems like this is running for every update, the `IF UPDATE(<FIELD>)` always validates to true, I guess this is something to do with the software being used.

**$64,000* question:**

How can I test for an update of a `text` column in an after update trigger if I can't access the `deleted` or `inserted` values of the column?

Before you ask, I can't change the column type.

**Not a real prize*

Comment: what a pk_key on NotesEdited table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can compare last `NotesEditHistory.NotesAfter` with `Note` and insert if they are not equal

Comment: Do you mean go and get the `NotesAfter` from the history table and get the `Note` field from the current value? I guess to do this I'd have to alter the history table to keep the note primary key in an indexed column?

Comment: @bendataclear yes i mean that. second for performance? you need just `select top 1 NotesAfter from NotesEditHistory order by  DateEdited desc` in this case index on DateEdited would be good

Comment: I'd need the note promary to find the specific note as there are thousands of notes in the db, but this sounds like a workable option, I'll do some testing on performance as I don't want it to hold up updates.

Comment: @bendataclear, include in index node id as well as date of course

Comment: @bendataclear about performance - if you include note column in update statement only if user actually update note, then update(note) will be true and check with NotesEditHistory will be executed only after actual editing. Frequency of such manual operations a always not high.

Comment: The update statements are generated dynamically within software I have no control over and include EVERY field for some stupid reason.

Comment: I have created the new trigger and added tables columns as suggested and it works very well, only a few MS added to the update time.